# Using ComboBox.DataSource item on selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I have binded ComboBox data sources to dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Size> modes = new Dictionary<string, Size>();

    public void setModes()
    {
        modes.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++)
        {
            string resolution_size = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.ToString();
            modes.Add(resolution_size, videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize);
        }

        comboBoxModes.DataSource = new BindingSource(modes, null);

        comboBoxModes.DisplayMember = "Key";
        comboBoxModes.ValueMember = "Value";

        comboBoxModes.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBoxModes_SelectedValueChanged);
        comboBoxModes.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
```

But how to retrieve selected mode and pass it to `videoSource.VideoResolution`:

```
    private void comboBoxModes_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoSource.VideoResolution = 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Dictionary.ContainsKey` method to get items from the dictionary .

```
 private void comboBoxModes_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (modes.ContainsKey(comboBoxModes.Text))
    {
        Size value = modes[comboBoxModes.Text];
        videosource.VideoResolution = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every item inside the combobox is a `KeyValuePair<string, Size>`

So it is just

```
private void comboBoxModes_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check for null because you will be called when SelectedIndex = -1
    if(comboBoxMode.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, Size> selection = comboBoxModes.SelectedItem;
        videoSource.VideoResolution = selection.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is initialiy null because you set the SelectedIndex = -1. You need to add a check before using the item